# Does Java Spring provide any routing system similar to Symfony2 routing system?

Tags: spring, symfony

I'm new in Spring but have some experience regarding Symfony2. I like routing system of Symfony. Does Spring MVC provide any thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes however its all done with annotations above a function rather than putting it into a file and then referencing that file.  It would look something like this

```
@RequestMapping({"/configuration/{configurationId}/banners"})
public String Foo(@PathVariable long configurationId) {
        //do something here 
        return "the return";
    }
```

You can also do a lot with security where you can blanket a permission for a particular directory.  Like this

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/page1" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/page2" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/page3/page4" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/page5" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Annotation ok, but do it have something like routing.yml.. so You can pass route name to view Resolver and href will be automatically generated? Or just attnotations? security is not important in this case.

Comment: I have never used another method other than annotations however it does look likes it possible.  You may want to take a look at apache camel.  But unfortunately I don't have much help to offer on that front.

Comment: @kingkong did you find any other method?

Comment: No, I use attnotation plus spring security java configuration

Comment: So then my answer is correct?  Can you mark it correct please?